# Android - HDPI screen as Normal?

Tags: android, screen-resolution, dpi

I have a really weird problem. I'm working with a Buildroid emulator because it's fast. First I was using a 720x1280-16 resolution. In my program, I used a bit of code to determine the density of the layout type of the screen (LDPI, MDPI, HDPI or XHDPI) :

```
switch (getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) {
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL :
        Log.d(TAG + " - Screen Resolution", "Small"); break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL :
        Log.d(TAG + " - Screen Resolution", "Normal"); break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE :
        Log.d(TAG + " - Screen Resolution", "Large"); break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE :
        Log.d(TAG + " - Screen Resolution", "XLarge"); break;
    default :
        Log.d(TAG + " - Screen Resolution", "Undefined or Mask"); break;
}
```

This worked fine, it showed me that the screen is `Large` and everything was cool... until I changed the DPI of the screen from 160 to 320, and now it's showing the screen as `Normal`

[image]

Graphics are messed up, the map isn't properly zoomed... and it happens that my boss' phone has the same DPI...

Can anyone explain this ?